# Add WPF Geometry from resource to GeometryGroup

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So i know that i can do this

```
<Path Grid.Column="0" Width="16" Height="16" Fill="{DynamicResource WindowForegroundBrush}" Stretch="Uniform">
    <Path.Data>
        <GeometryGroup >
            <Geometry>some geometry data1</Geometry>
            <Geometry>some geometry data2</Geometry>
            <Geometry>some geometry data3</Geometry>
        </GeometryGroup>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

But now i would like to move Geometry data 1, 2 and 3 into a resource dictionary

```
---resource dictionary---

<Geometry x:Key="data1">some geometry data1</Geometry>
<Geometry x:Key="data2">some geometry data2</Geometry>
<Geometry x:Key="data2">some geometry data3</Geometry>

---resource dictionary end---

<Path Grid.Column="0" Width="16" Height="16" Fill="{DynamicResource WindowForegroundBrush}" Stretch="Uniform">
    <Path.Data>
        <GeometryGroup >

        </GeometryGroup>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

How do i add the geometry from my resources to my geometrygroup?
Is ther some kind of binding or styling i could do?

I would prefere xaml only solution but all solutione are welcome.

Hope this make sens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
<Path ...>
    <Path.Data>
        <GeometryGroup>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="data1"/>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="data2"/>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="data3"/>
        </GeometryGroup>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Comment: Hahahaa.... Some times it is like my brain isn't working. The solution is so obvious.... that is two hours I will never see again. thanks for the help:)